# Cygwin EMacs GDB cannot debug NASM-64 source

Tags: emacs, gdb, cygwin, nasm

I have a 64-bit NASM exe written as a console app.  I want to debug it using gdb in Emacs under Cygwin.  I compiled and assembled using the following command strings:

```
nasm -f elf64 Prime_Number_EXE.asm 
gcc -g -l cygwin Prime_Number_EXE.o -o Prime_Number_EXE.exe
```

After compiling and linking, I go to cygwin and start emacs.  I open the nasm source file.  Then I start gdb and switch to gdb-many-windows mode.  But the source file showing in the source window is not my nasm code; it's a special C program that Cygwin inserts that says

```
/* libcmain.c
This file is part of Cygwin.
/* Allow apps which don't have a main to work, as long as they define WinMain */
```

So it doesn't show the nasm source code, and when I step through it, it will not stop at any breakpoints in the nasm source code.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

elf64 is NOT the structure of windows/cygwin program that is COFF,
You can not run elf64 on windows.

You are looking at the STUB gcc added to all the program.
For what you are trying to do you need a Unix/Linux system or
change to COFF structure.